# Why can I not drag and drop files from nautilus file manager to firefox in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: nautilus, firefox, files, drag-and-drop

I try to drag and drop a file from nautilus to firefox but can't do that.

Comment: Works for me for an image file and a small sound file. You'll need to provide more information. What sort of files are you trying to drag-n-drop? Are they very big? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: can't drag and drop any kind of file

Comment: also I have 4 GB of ram. not working for any file(small file also)

Comment: Can you drag-n-drop anything from anywhere to anywhere else or is your problem specific to "nautilus to firefox"?

Comment: Does this help in any way https://askubuntu.com/questions/973128/drag-and-drop-not-working-inside-nautilus-on-ubuntu-17-10?

Comment: not worked above. and not working for chromium also.problem is for nautilus to browser

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences > Views > Experimental
Is "Use the new views" checked? If so, uncheck it and you should be able to do drag-and-drop.

Note that, even with the "new views" enabled, drag-and-drop is still possible from the "list view", but not from the "icon view".

**edit** In recent versions of Nautilus, the 'Experimental' section in the preferences as disappered, and the "new view" seems to be the only one available now, :-/ Note however that it is only for the "icon view". As stated above, switching any Nautilus window to "list view" enables drag-n-drop to other apps. If you want to do it from the Desktop, you have to open it in a window ("Show Desktop in Files").

Comment: not working for me

Comment: is the problem specific to firefox?, can you drag and drop between 2 nautilus windows?

Comment: Yes problem is with browsers like Firefox , chromium and Nautilus.  And also not working for 2 different Nautilus Windows

Comment: Can't drag and drop files using dock

Comment: I have the same problem. I can drag files between and within Nautilus windows, but not to any other application.

Comment: This doesn't work in list view for me. Trying to drop a file into WeTransfer

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was having the dragged files on a network drive (smb). Copying them locally before drag helped.