# How to enable cursor edge dragging (Drag and Drop) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, cursor, drag-and-drop

While dragging I want to enable dragging on the edge of track pad (like in drag and drop).

I could not find a switch for it.

Comment: This helps me https://askubuntu.com/a/1041795/146752

Comment: But unfortunately this is just workaround :(